# Center image in frame instead of resizing?

Tags: html

Normally, the HTML `<img>` tag squeezes the image if the `width` or `height` attribute is smaller than the image itself. Is there a way to instead make it crop it if the specified size is smaller?

Comment: what about putting it in a container that you "crop" and setting overflow to hidden on the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the image as a background of a wrapper `div` and set the `div`'s `width` and `height`. Or you can add a wrapper element around the `img` and set height and width to the wrapper element.

See
http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/zFMfj/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with the img tag by itself, however there are a number of ways you could do this with the image file and another tag (canvas->DrawImage, Div->Background Image or Div->Oveflow: hidden) for example.